# How to pick directory (not file) in IDO mode, emacs-24

Tags: dired, emacs24, ido

IDO mode is awesome. It's essential to know the basic shortcuts, especially the escape hatch Ctrl-f ([introduction-to-ido-mode/](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/10/10/introduction-to-ido-mode/)) which gets you out of ido-mode.

In dired, if I want to copy a file to a directory, I can't seem to use ido to pick the directory, not can I even use the current ido directory that I've navigated to. There should be some way to say "pick directory" or at least enable the ctrl-f option to use the current spot in IDO. Does anybody know how to do this? (yes, you can disable ido mode for dired, but that is not what I want to do).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `C-j`, which is bound to `(ido-select-text)` and selects the buffer currently named by the prompt, which might be a directory as well.

Answer (score 28):

You can use "C-d" in ido mode, minibuffer

Comment: Not sure the reason for the downvote, this worked for me.  C-d is easier to remember than C-j for choosing a directory.

Comment: "C-d" is bound to "delete-char" in the default Emacs keybindings, so this will not work for most people.

Comment: @Bklyn: I don't think that's the case. `C-d` is bound to ido-magic-delete-char in the minibuffer, and the documentation says `"If at end of user input, perform magic actions: C-x C-f ... C-d  enter 'dired' on current directory."`

Comment: Weirdly, this didn't work for me (Emacs 26.1). I verified with "C-h k" that C-d is actually bound to ido-magic-delete-char in an ido minibuffer. "C-j" answered above does work.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative is to enable

```
(setq ido-show-dot-for-dired t)
```

and then you can open directories by opening the `.` file which will always be the first entry for a directory that you descend into.

Comment: I don't like that C-x C-f bound to ido-find-file does not accept dir as input, but this solution works acceptably